# Detect rows where uniqueness is not given in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Currently I have the following problem. I have to check if there is an infringement if the column values `ID`, `table` and `value_a` are not unique.

```
    df = pl.DataFrame(
        {
        "ID": ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1"],
        "column": ["foo", "foo", "bar", "ham", "egg"],
        "table": ["A", "A", "C", "D", "E"],
        "value_a": ["tree", tree, None, "bean", None,],
        "value_b": ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dal", "Curry", "Dish",],
        "mandatory": ["M", "M", "M", "CM", "M"]
        }
    )
    print(df)
    shape: (5, 6)
    ┌─────┬────────┬───────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
    │ ID  ┆ column ┆ table ┆ value_a ┆ value_b ┆ mandatory │
    │ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
    │ str ┆ str    ┆ str   ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str       │
    ╞═════╪════════╪═══════╪═════════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
    │ 1   ┆ foo    ┆ A     ┆ tree    ┆ Lorem   ┆ M         │
    │ 1   ┆ foo    ┆ B     ┆ tree    ┆ Ipsum   ┆ M         │
    │ 1   ┆ bar    ┆ C     ┆ null    ┆ Dal     ┆ M         │
    │ 1   ┆ ham    ┆ D     ┆ bean    ┆ Curry   ┆ M         │
    │ 1   ┆ egg    ┆ E     ┆ null    ┆ Dish    ┆ M         │
    └─────┴────────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────────┘
```

In the case of df a infringement report should be created with the following dedicated output:

```
shape: (2, 8)
┌───────┬─────┬────────┬───────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ index ┆ ID  ┆ column ┆ table ┆ value_a ┆ value_b ┆ mandatory ┆ warning                 │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---       ┆ ---                     │
│ i64   ┆ str ┆ str    ┆ str   ┆ str     ┆ str     ┆ str       ┆ str                     │
╞═══════╪═════╪════════╪═══════╪═════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1   ┆ foo    ┆ A     ┆ tree    ┆ Lorem   ┆ M         ┆ Row value is not unique │
│ 1     ┆ 1   ┆ foo    ┆ A     ┆ tree    ┆ Ipsum   ┆ M         ┆ Row value is not unique │
└───────┴─────┴────────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────────┴─────────────────────────┘
```

The report should contain an `index` and a `warning` column. I used this line of code to identify if there are any null values in a row:

```
report = (df.with_row_count("index")
                .filter(pl.any(pl.col("*").is_null()) & pl.col("mandatory").eq("M"))
                .with_columns(pl.lit("Missing value detected").alias("warning"))
         )
```

How do I need to adapt this code  so on the one hand I detect missing values and on the other hand I identify ununique rows. Maybe I create two reports and use .vstack() to combine both reports to a final one. How would you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `struct` and use [`.is_duplicated`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_duplicated.html#polars-expr-is-duplicated)

```
df.with_columns(
   warning = pl.struct(["ID", "table", "value_a"]).is_duplicated()
)
```

```
shape: (5, 7)
┌─────┬────────┬───────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────────┬─────────┐
│ ID  | column | table | value_a | value_b | mandatory | warning │
│ --- | ---    | ---   | ---     | ---     | ---       | ---     │
│ str | str    | str   | str     | str     | str       | bool    │
╞═════╪════════╪═══════╪═════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪═════════╡
│ 1   | foo    | A     | tree    | Lorem   | M         | true    │
│ 1   | foo    | A     | tree    | Ipsum   | M         | true    │
│ 1   | bar    | C     | null    | Dal     | M         | false   │
│ 1   | ham    | D     | bean    | Curry   | CM        | false   │
│ 1   | egg    | E     | null    | Dish    | M         | false   │
└─────┴────────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: How would it look like when I want to combine your solution with the existing report  to detect not unique and missing values ?

Comment: Perhaps `.with_columns(pl.when(.is_null()).then("Missing").when(.is_duplicated()).then("Duplicated").alias("warning")).drop_nulls(subset="warning")`

Comment: when I use your approach, I receive this error: pyo3_runtime.PanicException: this operation is not implemented/valid for this dtype: Struct([Field { name: "ID", dtype: Utf8 }, Field { name: "column", dtype: Utf8 }, Field { name: "table", dtype: Utf8 }, Field { name: "value_a", dtype: Utf8 }])

../../.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/frame.py:1145: PanicException

Comment: Are you using the latest version of polars?

Comment: I am using v0.16.4

Comment: `.struct().is_duplicated` was added in [v0.16.6](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.16.6)